# Django filter a prefetched queryset returning an empty list

Tags: python, django, prefetch

In my app I have some Users and Groups, that are related by a many to many relation through GroupMember.

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...

class Group(models.Model):
    ...
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='groups.GroupMember', related_name='groups')


class GroupMember(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='group_members', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='members', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now I am trying to build an endpoint that retrieves a list of user instances that are in any one of the groups that your user is in. So if user A and B are in group1, user A and C are in group2, and C and D are in group3, retrieving the users as A would return B and C (since those are in groups with A).

That filter part can be done in multiple ways, but the part where I am stuck is how to show **which groups** were the cause of the relation. I tried to use prefetch_related with a custom filter, to fetch only the groups that have user A in them, like this:

```
User.objects.exclude(id=user.id).annotate(
    # Annotate the amount of groups related between the users
    related_group_count=Count('groups', filter=Q(groups__users=user))
).filter(
    # Only users that have at least 1 relation with this user
    related_group_count__gt=0
).prefetch_related(
    # Prefetch the specific groups to show
    Prefetch('groups', User.groups.all(), to_attr='related_groups'),
)
```

The returned users will not have any `related_groups`, it will be an empty qs. When I include the request user (by removing the exclude part on the query), the groups *will* be available for that user, but still not any other. This is my current response (including the requesting user "A"):

```
{
    "first_name": "A",
    "related_groups": [
        {
            "name": "group1",
        },
        {
            "name": "group2",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "first_name": "B",
    "related_groups": []
},
{
    "first_name": "C",
    "related_groups": []
}
```

But I'm trying to achieve this:

```
{
    "first_name": "B",
    "related_groups": [
        {
            "name": "group1",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "first_name": "C",
    "related_groups": [
        {
            "name": "group2",
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem lies with the filter on the Prefetch queryset, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong or if this is even possible. I tried different way of filtering (also with `Group.objects.filter(users=user)`) or even annotating the group members, counting if the given user is in that group and filtering on that, but with no success...

---

Note: This only happens when filtering the prefetch as described above: User (is group member) -> Group -> User (group member). It looks like the filter is "overwriting" the user in the queryset with the initial user (A).

In my project I work with multiple group-like concepts, one of which has 2 different kind of members (lets say, in context of this question a second GroupMember type model, with an additional many to many relation in the group model to user). When using User (group member) -> Group -> User (other kind of member), the prefetch actually works as expected. This issue is only when prefetching using the same through-model in relation to the user.

Comment: Have you tried a filter along the lines of `Q(groups__in=user.groups.all())`? Sometimes these nested queries get restricted to a specific related object.

Comment: Are you referring to the filter in the annotation? That doesnt change anything, sadly. Even when only calling `prefetch_related` on the main queryset (without annotate and filter before), the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work, by using a separate queryset that gets the group ids. This way the prefetch filter will not use the requesting user id to filter, which resulted in empty lists for all other users.

```
group_ids = user.groups.values('pk')

User.objects.exclude(id=user.id).filter(
    groups__in=group_ids
).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('groups', Group.objects.filter(id__in=group_ids), to_attr='related_groups'),
)
```